# Como converter pixel em dp?

Tags: android, android-layout

Fiz um aplicativo que é um formulário, e fiz tudo via código sem usar xml, portanto meus textViews e Edittexts ficaram em pixels.

No tablet funciona bem, mas no celular com resolução menor ficou tudo "encavalado".

Comment: Poderia postar um trecho do seu código? Facilita o "mostrar como".

Answer (score 2):

Para que as dimensões se mantenha consistentes entre os vários tipos de tela deverá pensar em termos de dp e não pixel.

Como a maioria(eu diria todos mas não tenho a certeza) dos métodos que usam dimensões são expressas em pixeis deverá converter os dps em pixeis.

Para fazer essa conversão pode usar o seguinte método:

```
public static int convertDpToPixels(float dp, Activity context){

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    float density = metrics.density;
    return (int) Math.ceil(dp * density);
}
```

Comment: Com este código, no meu celular em vez dos campos diminuírem já que a tela é menor, a textView ficou ainda maior.

Comment: O uso da unidade dp não diminui nem aumenta o tamanho das views. Ela mantém o tamanho delas qualquer que seja a densidade da tela. O que acontece no seu celular é a ilusão de ficar maior porque a tela é muito mais pequena que a do *tablet*.  A solução para isso é ter um xml para ser usado no caso de telas pequena e outro para o caso de telas maiores. Veja [aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) como.

Comment: é isso mesmo, a escola do tablet é 1.0 e do celular 2.0, então vou ver aqui o que faço. mas obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Tente algo assim:

```
public static int converteDpParaPx(Context context, int dps) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dps, displayMetrics));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso uma classe auxiliar para trabalhar com as conversões de unidades.

```
package com.example;

import android.content.res.Resources;

public class UnityConverter {

    private static float scaleFactor = 1;

    private UnityConverter() {

    }

    /**
     * Configura o conversor de acordo com o device do usuário.
     * 
     * @param res
     *            os resources da aplicação
     */
    public static void config(Resources res) {
        scaleFactor = res.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }

    /**
     * Converte um valor numerico para a unidade dp sem arredondamento
     * 
     * @param value
     *            o valor a ser convertido
     * @return o valor em dp's
     */
    public static float toDp(float value) {
        return value * scaleFactor;
    }

    /**
     * Converte um valor numerico para a unidade dp sem arredondamento
     * 
     * @param value
     *            o valor a ser convertido
     * @return o valor em dp's
     */
    public static float toDp(int value) {
        return value * scaleFactor;
    }

    /**
     * Converte um valor numerico para a unidade dp arredondado
     * 
     * @param value
     *            o valor a ser convertido
     * @return o valor em dp's
     */
    public static int toRoundDp(float value) {
        return (int) (value * scaleFactor);
    }

    /**
     * Converte um valor numerico para a unidade dp arredondado
     * 
     * @param value
     *            o valor a ser convertido
     * @return o valor em dp's
     */
    public static int toRoundDp(int value) {
        return (int) (value * scaleFactor);
    }
}
```

Uso

```
UnityConverter.config(getResources());
int dp = UnityConverter.toRoundDp(120)
```