# É possível utilizar variáveis para definir o tamanho de uma View?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento e aplicativos e na aplicação em que estou trabalhando preciso que o usuário me dê um valor (distância em metros) e a partir deste valor eu ajustarei o tamanho da imagem a ser exibida pelo aplicativo.
Estou desenvolvendo em Java com o Android Studio.

Pensei em fazer isso utilizando variáveis que seriam usadas para definir meu valores de altura e largura, por exemplo:

```
android:layout_width= variavel_w
android:layout_height= variavel_h
```

porém não se é possível utilizar variáveis nesses campos, ou se haveria alguma outra forma de ajustar o tamanho da minha imagem conforme alguma entrada.
Ficarei muito grato com qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível, mas não no xml.

Tem de usar o objecto Java que representa essa ImageView e o seu objecto LayoutParams.

Obtenha o objecto da sua ImageView:

```
final ImageView aSuaImageView = findViewById(R.id.aSuaImageView);
```

Obtenha o seu objecto LayoutParams:

```
//Substitua LinearLayout. por RelativeLayout. se for o caso
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) aSuaImageView.getLayoutParams();
```

Atribua os valores pretendidos para *width* e *height*

```
layoutParams.width = 100; // Pode usar uma variável
layoutParams.height = 100; // Pode usar uma variável
```

A atribua o LayoutParams alterado à ImageView:

```
aSuaImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**Nota:**
Quando se especifica valores programaticamente no LayoutParams, os atributos `width` e `height` esperam que esses valores sejam **pixeis**.
Para que haja consistência das dimensões entre os vários tipos de tela, tem de considerar as dimensões em **dp** e convertê-las para pixeis antes de as atribuir aos atributos.
Veja nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/96277/2541) como fazer a conversão.